# how to get the last inserted id using cs cart query format?

Tags: php, cs-cart

How to get Last inserted id

```
$datass = array (
    'object_id' => $id,
    'object_type'=>$ty,
    'type' => $t,
    'company_id'=>$c
);
return(db_query("INSERT INTO ?:discussion ?e", $datass));
```

Now i need to get the last inserted id ? how i do.

Comment: $lastInsertID = db_query("INSERT INTO ?:discussion ?e", $datass);

Answer (score 1):

Query for find last inserted  value must be

```
select * from tablename order by desc id limit 0,1
```

here id must be primary key

Try this:-

```
db_query('select * from tablename order by desc id limit 0,1');
```

Comment: I use this on .But in yii Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();So i think cscart have any format for get last insert id ?

Comment: its not working .I tryed this one.db_get_row("SELECT * FROM ?:images order by image_id  desc limit 1 ")

Comment: @SoniyaKaliappan :- db_get_row("SELECT * FROM images order by image_id desc limit 0,1 "). Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also.

```
db_get_field('SELECT MAX(field_name) FROM ?:table_name');
```